# Efficient way to change passwords for multiple users

Tags: parse-platform

Due to a unprecedented flaw in the way I set up the system to login users, I would like to change passwords for multiple users based off of existing user data. (Users won't care since they are logging in through a one-click gateway).

Is there any way to do this in parse.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a background job for handling this maintenance:

```
Parse.Cloud.job('fixUserStuffs', function(request, status) {

  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.each(function(user) {
    var newPassword = // do something to generate password.
    user.setPassword(newPassword);
    return user.save();
  }).then(function() {
    status.success('All done!');
  });

});
```

Then deploy and run this job ad-hoc through the dashboard.  All users will have their passwords changed.

Comment: is there any way to console.log within the query.each function? I'm not getting any output and I'm not sure if it's getting executed.

Comment: i'm not getting any output in my console, am i doing somethign wrong?

Comment: I'm getting this problem: "error":"success/error was not called

Comment: so i finally got everything to work! but I'm getting this error: " Failed with: Cannot iterate on a query with sort, skip, or limit." since I add a query.limit = 1000. What would be a good way around this?

Comment: You don't add a limit. the each method will process *all* records.